# Like SQL com vários campos

Tags: php, mysql

Quero fazer um `select` para uma busca de cinco campos (cargo, formação, sexo, horario, fotografia). Mas não está funcionando.

Alguém poderia me dizer o motivo?

```
<?php

$cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
$formacao = $_POST['formacao'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$horario = $_POST['horario'];
$fotografia = $_POST['fotografia'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_cadastro_curriculo WHERE ((cargo LIKE '%".$cargo."%') OR (formacao LIKE '%".$formacao."%') OR (sexo LIKE '%".$sexo."%')
            OR (sexo LIKE '%".$sexo."%') OR (horario LIKE '%".$horario."%') OR (fotografia LIKE '%".$fotografia."%')) LIMIT ".$ini.",".$fim);

if ($sql && mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {     
   ...
}            
?>
```

Comment: Separando por virgulas cargo,formacao,horario etc..não funciona?

Comment: Consegui resolver. Troquei o OR por AND.

Comment: Coloca sua resposta para outras pessoas

Answer (score 2):

Segue a resposta que encontrei:

```
<?php
$total = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*)TOTAL FROM tbl_cadastro_curriculo' );

$cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
$formacao = $_POST['formacao'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$horario = $_POST['horario'];
$fotografia = $_POST['fotografia'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_cadastro_curriculo WHERE ((cargo LIKE '%".$cargo."%') AND (formacao LIKE '%".$formacao."%') AND (sexo LIKE '%".$sexo."%')
            AND (sexo LIKE '%".$sexo."%') AND (horario LIKE '%".$horario."%') AND (fotografia LIKE '%".$fotografia."%')) LIMIT ".$ini.",".$fim);

if ($sql && mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
   .....
}            
?>
```